# How to find and replace second comma (,) with - in a dataframe using Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, find, find-replace

I have dataframe like :

| Name | Address |
| --- | --- |
| Anuj | Anuj,Sinha,BB |
| Sinha | Sinha,Anuj BB |

In column Adrress, I want to replace all comma (,) except the fist comma in all row with -.

Can anyone please suggest me the possible solution?

provided:

```
df.dtypes

Customer ID               Int64
First_name-Last_name     string
Address                  string
Phone                    string
Secondary_station        string
Customer_disconnected    string
```

Comment: Can you share expected output ?

Comment: Can there be more than 2 commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a maximum of 2 commas, you can use this simple regex:

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.replace('(,.*),', r'\1-')
```

output:

```
    Name        Address
0   Anuj  Anuj,Sinha-BB
1  Sinha  Sinha,Anuj BB
```

If there are possibly more than 2 commas, you can do:

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: x[0]+','+'-'.join(x[1:]))
```

or, more efficient:

```
splits = df['Address'].str.split(',', 1)
df['Address'] = splits.str[0]+','+splits.str[1].str.replace(',', '-')
```

Comment: Hi @mozway , Can you help with another simillar issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68935152/how-to-find-and-add-string-in-a-dataframe-if-there-is-no-number-or-bb-or-b-b)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function this way :

```
txt = "I like bananas"

x = txt.replace("bananas", "apples")

print(x)
```

It will display :

> I like apples

For your dataframe, you just need to iterate thought your values this way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name': ['Anuj', 'Sinha'],
        'adresse': ['Anuj,Sinha,BB', 'Sinha,Anuj BB']
    }
)
for colunm in df.columns:
    for index, value in enumerate(df[colunm]):
        df[colunm][index] = value.replace(',', '-')

print(df)
```

It will display :

```
    name        adresse
0   Anuj  Anuj-Sinha-BB
1  Sinha  Sinha-Anuj BB
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, I understand this one but, this will replace all commas(,). I want to leave first comma, as it is and all other comma should be replaced with (-) dash.