# How to find and add string in a dataframe? if there is no 'number' or BB or B.B at the end of the row in a column, I need to add BB at the end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, str-replace, data-cleaning

I have dataframe like :

| Name | Address |
| --- | --- |
| ramesh | Anuj,Sinha-34 |
| suresh | Sinha,Anuj B.B |
| kale | rat,sresh |
| Naresh | rate,hug BB |

In column Address, if there is no 'number' or BB or B.B or B.B. at the end, I need to add BB at the end. (using pandas-Python)

provided:

```
df.dtypes

Name     string
Address  string
```

Hint:

```
dfn['Address_new1'] = dfn['Address'].str.replace('(,.*),', r'\1 BB')
```

using this code-line, I can replace the , with (space)BB for example, how to add more search and find options like int, BB,B.B,B.B. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` and check two conditions with `or` `|`. If the conditions are satisfied, you can add BB at the end, and if not, you can return the Address column as it is. To illustrate:

```
import numpy as np

df['new'] = np.where( (df['Address'].str[-1].str.isnumeric()) \
                     | (df['Address'].str[-4:].str.replace('.','').str.endswith('BB')),\
                        df['Address'],df['Address'].add(' BB')\
                        )
```

Which prints back:

```
>>> df

     Name         Address             new
0  ramesh   Anuj,Sinha-34   Anuj,Sinha-34
1  suresh  Sinha,Anuj B.B  Sinha,Anuj B.B
2    kale       rat,sresh    rat,sresh BB
3  Naresh     rate,hug BB     rate,hug BB
```

The conditions that we are checking is whether the last character of the Address column is numeric, or whether the last 4 characters in the Address column (once we replace the `.`) contain 'BB'